# Find inverse with minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Give $a=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$, I need to find the minimal polynomial of $a$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ with $f(a)=a^{-1}$.

Now the first part is rather easy, but how do I calculate the second part?

Comment: Just play with the powers of $a$.  You have $a^3=18\sqrt 3+14\sqrt 5$ so $ \sqrt 5=\frac 14(a-a^3)$.  Get a similar expression for $\sqrt 3$.  Use those two expressions to get $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Give $a=\sqrt3+\sqrt5$, I need to find the minimal polynomial of $a$.

$$\begin{align}
a=\sqrt3+\sqrt5 &\quad\Rightarrow\quad
a^2=(\sqrt3+\sqrt5)^2 = 8+2\sqrt{15}\\
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad (a^2-8)^2 = 4\cdot15\\
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0=a^4-16a^2+4\\
\end{align}$$

> $a^{-1}$

$$0=a^4-16a^2+4 \;\Leftrightarrow\; 0=a^3-16a+4a^{-1}$$
Thus
$$a^{-1}=-\frac14a^3+4a$$

Comment: Is it really that simple? Thank you!

Comment: For $a^{-1}$, yes.  For the minimal polynomial you'd also  have to show that no polynomial of smaller degree will do.

Comment: thank you but the polynomial is the same I found as well, it is normed, has a root in $a$ and is irreducible with Eisenstein with $p=2$. So it is the minimal polynomial.